# What does "To avoid IP issues" mean?

Tags: sentence, meaning

I'm following a discussion on a public forum and, one of the users replied the following:

> Hmmm....I honestly never dealt with large arrays like that.
>   Can you post a screen grab of what you typically do? Even if it's just a bogus example (to avoid IP issues).

What does `to avoid IP issues` mean in this sentence? I can only find references to IP as in IP-adress.

The discussion is about large arrays in Autodesk Inventor (drafting package).

Comment: *IP* = *Intellectual Property*.

Comment: They mean to remove anything from the data that is covered by some intellectual property, such as a patent, copyright, trademark or trade secret. Anything you do for your employer with data is typically considered at least a trade secret. It's also possibly a violation of your terms of service with your customers to publish their data on the internet. Even if none of this is the case, it's prudent to use fake data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case IP stands for intellectual property.

The person is asking for a screenshot, but it may not be possible to post one online because the content may be copyrighted, or owned by someone other than the user in the forum.